# GeoExt2 WmsCapabilitiesLayerStore adding layer

Tags: extjs, geoext

I use Ext 4.2.1 and GeoExt2 for building mapviewer app. I defined a `WmsCapabilitiesLayerStore`

in grid to adding layers to map. It works but some wms layers adding base layer. Normally when user clicks the layer in the grid, selected layer will be added to overlay layers.

What is the reason of this?